# I have an issue with my overlay hamburger menu into ReactJS project

Tags: reactjs

I just start figure out with ReactJS, and I think because I have the my current issue. The essence of the problem: I created the overlay menu it's activate by click on hamburger. This works pretty well, but... when the user clicks on a menu item and navigates to another page, the menu stays open, overlapping the content of the open page. I tried to deal with it myself but it turned out even worse.

Here is my components code example:

**//Hamburger Menu Button Component**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export function HamburgerMenuButton({ onClick }) {

const[isToggled, setIsToggled] = useState(false);
const handleClick = () => setIsToggled(!isToggled);

  const handleClicks = () => {
   onClick();
   handleClick();
 }  

return (

<div onClick={handleClicks} className={isToggled ? "hamburger active" : "hamburger"}>
  <div className="burger"></div>
</div> 
 
);
}
```

**//Menu Component**

```
import React from "react";
import {Link}  from "react-router-dom"

function Menu({ expanded, onMenuItemClick }){ 

return(

    <div className={expanded ? 'active menu-wrapper' : 'menu-wrapper'} >
    <ul>
        <li  className="menu-item" onClick={onMenuItemClick}><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li className="menu-item" onClick={onMenuItemClick}><Link to="/projects">Projects</Link></li>
        <li className="menu-item" onClick={onMenuItemClick}><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
    </ul>
</div>

) }

 export default Menu;
```

**//Header Component**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {Link}  from "react-router-dom"
import { HamburgerMenuButton } from './HamburgerMenuButton';

function Header({ onMenuToggle, onMenuItemClick }){ 

const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      if (window.scrollY > 0) {
        setIsActive(true);
      } else {
        setIsActive(false);
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
}, []);

return(
<header className={isActive ? 'header active' : 'header' }>
    <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="header-inner">
                  <figure>
                    <Link to="/">
                      <img width={90} height={37} src="/img/logo.png" className="logo" alt="main_logo"/>
                    </Link>
                  </figure>
                <HamburgerMenuButton onClick={onMenuToggle} onMenuItemClick={onMenuItemClick} />
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
   </header>
 
  ) }

 export default Header;
```

And here is the last Footer component because the menu component placed here:

```
import Menu from "./Menu";
import { useState } from "react";

 function Footer({ menuExpanded }){ 

const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(true)
const handleMenuItemClick = () => {
    setMenuOpen(false)
}

return(

<footer className="footer">

    <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
            <ul className="footer-menu">
                <li><a href="https://rhinebrand-agency.de/impressum">Impressum</a></li> 
                <li><a href="https://rhinebrand-agency.de/impressum">Datenschutzerklärung</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    {menuOpen ? <Menu expanded={menuExpanded} onMenuItemClick={handleMenuItemClick}/> : null}

</footer>

) }

export default Footer;
```

Yes, there is a lot of code here because I want to show all the components that are involved in the output and operation of the menu. Most likely this is not the correct structure, but I'm not familiar with the best practices. Therefore, I need help on how to get rid of my problem in this context.

In this part of the code, I made sure that the menu still closes when you go to another page.

```
econst [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(true)
const handleMenuItemClick = () => {
    setMenuOpen(false)
}
{menuOpen ? <Menu expanded={menuExpanded} onMenuItemClick={handleMenuItemClick}/> : null}
```

But after the transition, it no longer works until you reload the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day and a half, I still figured out this problem and completely redid the logic of my menu. Here is my new version which works great:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function FullscreenOverlayMenu() {
const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
function handlePopState(event) {
  setMenuOpen(false);
}

window.addEventListener("popstate", handlePopState);

return () => {
  window.removeEventListener("popstate", handlePopState);
};
}, []);

return (
<div>
  <button className="menu-btn" onClick={() => setMenuOpen(!menuOpen)}>
    Toggle Menu
  </button>
  {menuOpen && (
    <div className="fullscreen-overlay-menu">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/" onClick={() => setMenuOpen(false)}>
            Home
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/contact" onClick={() => setMenuOpen(false)}>
            Contact
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>Menu item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )}
</div>
);
}

export default FullscreenOverlayMenu;
```

I'm glad I figured this out on my own!